# Black screen after lid close, but only with NVIDIA drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 17.04

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 on an ASUS UX303 notebook. This laptop has two GPUs: an integrated Intel one, and a discrete NVIDIA 940M. I recently decided to install the non-nouveau NVIDIA drivers (specifically, nvidia-381), but after doing so, I encountered a problem: whenever I open the lid after closing it, I get a completely black screen. If I leave the laptop on the black screen for long enough, I hear the fan begin to go crazy.

When my screen goes completely black, I can't Control-Alt-FX my way over to any consoles. The only thing that I can do is hold down the power button. This issue isn't only happening with the nvidia-381 driver -- I've tried the nvidia-375 and nvidia-378 drivers, and yet the problem still persists. I've also tried to uninstall these drivers and install Nouveau, but I've had my own problems with that (when I install the Nouveau drivers from software-properties-gtk, I get weird screen tearing and lshw tells me that the 3D controller is unclaimed). At this point, my Ubuntu system is more borked than it was before I installed any drivers, Nouveau, NVIDIA, or otherwise. Could anyone please tell me how I can remedy this issue?

For reference, here's my `lshw -C video` output:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 520
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:124 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 940M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
```

And here is my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Once again, I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 with my Asus R558UQ. It's far from being a solution, but to me disabling the Secure Boot in BIOS/UEFI menu prevented the black screen from reappearing.

---

**EDIT**: This worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04.

**DISCLAIMER** : I didn't came up with this solution. It was an issue I've had problems with so long that I decided to save the answer as a PDF in my Google Driver so as not to loose it. And now I can't find the link, so **I'm copypasting someone's else answer**.

---

Hi all

How to solve the issues of suspending , hibernating and wakeup with nvidia-370.28 first step :
Just open this file
sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla and enable hibernation

...
[Disable hibernate by default in upower] Identity=unix-user:* Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate ResultActive=yes

[Disable hibernate by default in logind] Identity=unix-user:* Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate ResultActive=yes

second step :
on /etc/default/grub :

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1 vga=0 rdblacklist=nouveau nouveau.modeset=0 "

third step :
sudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules and add the following modules

nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm

fourth step :
sudo update-initframs -k "yourkernel" -u

fifth step :
reboot and you are done .
Note : if are not on Ubuntu follow this:

PolicyKit Local Authority policy to enable suspend and hibernate for all users. Should be installed into /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/90-mandatory.d or /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/90-mandatory.d

file to edit under the directory mentionned : enable-suspend-and-hibernate.pkla copy this text and save and continue other steps

[Completely disable suspend and hibernate]

Identity=unix-user:* Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend;org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.s uspend*;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate*
ResultAny=nyes ResultInactive=yes ResultActive=yes

regards Mounir

PS : I hope it works for you AMEN

---

For me, it not only prevented the black screen after hibernating but also solved the freezing when shutting down/restarting after hibernating using the Xorg drivers. 
Hope it works for you too, let me know :) !

Nehuen

Answer (score 0):

**I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and was having the same issue in my ASUS R542U,
it started when I installed the Nvidia drivers .
To solve the problem  I changed the option of suspending screen after closing the lid of laptop.**

---

## To do this, Type this in the terminal

***sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf***

---

**Now just change this line**

## #HandleLidSwitch=suspend

```
  TO
```

## HandleLidSwitch=ignore

And then save the file and reboot your system.
That should do it.

---

***Hope it helps.***